# I am encountering a problem sending/ receiving 2 or more messages from/to a module in OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++

I tried to use `send()` back to back but it generates an error. I'm very new to network simulation software. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide more details about your problem, and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you do not provide code, to your question. Without, that, it's just guessing, so here is mine. You are sending the same packet two times which is NOT possible. You have to create a copy of the packet (with `dup()`) and send that copy in the second call.

As a general advice: you should do the TicToc tutorial, before going any further into OMNeT++ programming.

Comment: I tried and it returns a cNonCopyableOwnedObject. The code line says:
cMessage *m1=dup() ;
Is the syntax correct?